# Update column value using where order by in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have table `tblOptionsAssets`

and it contains fields like these:

`id (Primary Key)`

`position_id (simply the position number used to arrange data from position_id number 1 up to last row)`

`height (int)`

I have sample records

`id     |    position_id    |  height`

`1      |         2         |    12`

`2      |         1         |    36`

`3      |         3         |    24`

I want to update `position_id` values `ASCENDINGLY` where the column `height` is ordered by ASC

Expected output:

`id     |    position_id    |  height`

`1      |         1         |    12`

`2      |         3         |    36`

`3      |         2         |    24`

So that if I select like this :

SELECT * FROM tblOptionsAssets ORDER BY position_id ASC

will return something like this

`id     |    position_id    |  height`

`1      |         1         |    12`

`3      |         2         |    24`

`2      |         3         |    36`

**UPDATE**

on my current setup, there are rows like these :

`id     |    position_id    |  height`

`1      |         2         |    12`

`2      |         1         |    36`

`3      |         3         |    24`

`4      |         4         |    36`

`5      |         5         |    36`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest actually *not* doing this update, as you can easily use `ROW_NUMBER` along with a view to generate the ordering you want here.  For example:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY height) AS position_id,
    height
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo